# Big-O and Cache Aware Data Structures & Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, caching, big-o

Is there someplace where I can get a Big-O style analysis / comparison of traditional data structures such as linked lists, various trees, hashes, etc vs. cache aware data structures such as Judy trees and others?

Answer (score 2):

Actually,

I would look [here](http://www.nothings.org/computer/judy/) for analysis of Judy Trees.

> As illustrated in this data, Judy's
>   smaller size does not give it an
>   enormous speed advantage over a
>   traditional "trade size for speed"
>   data structure. Judy has received
>   countless man-hours developing and
>   debugging 20,000 lines of code; I
>   spent an hour or three writing a
>   fairly standard 200-line hash table.
>
> If your data is strictly sequential;
>   you should use a regular array. If
>   your data is often sequential, or
>   approximately sequential (e.g. an
>   arithmetic sequence stepping by 64),
>   Judy might be the best data structure
>   to use. If you need to keep space to a
>   minimum--you have a huge number of
>   associative arrays, or you're only
>   storing very small values, Judy is
>   probably a good idea. If you need an
>   sorted iterator, go with Judy.
>   Otherwise, a hash table may be just as
>   effective, possibly faster, and much
>   simpler.

Answer (score 1):

BigO is about algorhitms comlexity doing certain task. 
There are different tasks avaliable on each data structure. Most important one are:
Sort, Find(in sorted structure) and add element.

So what are you looking for is complexity of certain task for certain data structure.

For most data types optimal sorting algorhitm is O(n*log(n)) but keep in mind that some structures are still slower, for instance sorting linked list is slower than arrays athough both have n*log(n) complexity

Answer (score 0):

Read [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html) books by Don Knuth. These are considered by many to be the best source of algorithm information around.

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking of something a bit more compact ;-)

Comment: Muvan Me'alyv - I don't know if SO will display Hebrew... בא נראה

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in: "Introduction to Algorithms"

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)